# Test method with okhttp3 call

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking, okhttp

I have a method in the service class that makes a call to an external api. How would I mock this okHttpClient call? I have tried to do so with mockito but no luck with that.

```
//this is the format of the method that i want to test
public string sendMess(EventObj event) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    //build payload using the information stored in the payload object
    ResponseBody body = 
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), payload);
    Request request = //built using the Requestbody
    //trying to mock a response from execute
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    //other logic
}
```

I am open to refactoring the service class if it helps with the testing. Any suggestions and recommendation is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What test case logic? The "other logic" that i am talking about is just formatting the response and returning it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `spring-boot` leave managing beans to spring.

1) First create `OkHttpClient` as spring bean so that you can use it all over application

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Bean
public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient();
    }
 }
```

2) And then in the service class `@Autowire` `OkHttpClient` and use it

```
@Service
public class SendMsgService {

@Autowired
private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

 public string sendMess(EventObj event) {

ResponseBody body =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), payload);
Request request = //built using the Requestbody
//trying to mock a response from execute
Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
//other logic
   }
 }
```

**Tests**

3) Now in the Test classes use `@SpringBootTest`,`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@MockBean`

> The @SpringBootTest annotation can be used when we need to bootstrap the entire container. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext that will be utilized in our tests.
>
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) is used to provide a bridge between Spring Boot test features and JUnit. Whenever we are using any Spring Boot testing features in out JUnit tests, this annotation will be required.
>
> @MockBean Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring ApplicationContext.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

 @Autowire
 private SendMsgService sendMsgService;

 @MockBean
 private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

  @Test
  public void testSendMsg(){

 given(this.okHttpClient.newCall(ArgumentMatchers.any())
            .execute()).willReturn(String);

  EventObj event = //event object
 String result = sendMsgService.sendMess(event);

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you pull out the instantiation of your `OkHttpClient` to an own method in a `Configuration` class. Afterwards you could `@Inject` the client anywhere it is needed and testing becomes much easier because you can `@Mock` it away.

Such to say the `Spring`-managed bean:

```
@Configuration
public class OkHttpClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }
}
```

…your production class:

```
@Component
public class ProductionClass {
    @Inject
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    public string sendMess(EventObj event) {
       okHttpClient // whatever you want
       […]
    }
}
```

…and your test:

```
public class SpyTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private ProductionClass productionClass;
    @Mock
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;


    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void spyInsteadOfPowermock() {
        Request request = // mock the request
        when(okHttpClient.newCall(request)).thenReturn(mock(Call.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I tried mocking okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute, this doesn't work because okHttpClient.newCall(request) is null since I cannot really mock that. The newCall returns a Call object which is then used to call the execute() method within Call.

Comment: Why can't you mock `okHttpClient.newCall(request)`? What type has your `request` object? If you can not mock `request` in general you are free to mock it with a `Matcher` like: `when(okHttpClient.newCall(any(RequestClass.class))).thenReturn(/*whateverResult*/);`.

Comment: Would i not need to mock the Call class since okHttpClient.newCall() returns a Call object?

Comment: Yeah exactly, sorry consider my `RequestClass.class` just as an example, I am not that familiar with the OkHttp API.